# For an outcome space $[0,2]$, why is the probability of event $A=\{1/2\}=0$?

Tags: probability

For an outcome space $[0,2]$, why is the probability of event $A=\{1/2\}=0$?

Why is this the case? is this the case for all numbers in the interval?

Answer (score 0):

If a set $X\subset A$ has probability $1$, then what is the probability of $A\setminus X$?

Comment: I think it would be 0?

Comment: @TanSriprai Exactly. And if $X\neq A$, then $A\setminus X\neq \emptyset$, right?

Comment: perhaps I wasn't clear about what I'm actually asking about. I think you are trying to make me realise that a probability of 0 does not mean the set is empty, but my question is more specifically about a real closed interval sample space and why if you pick a real number at random in that interval the probability that it is 1/2, or any number in that interval I presume,  is 0. Is it something to do with the fact that there are infinite numbers in that interval? Where can I see a proof of this? If i misunderstood you apologies. @5xum

Comment: @TanSriprai Ah, I understand the question now. Can you please edit your original question to make this more clear?

Comment: Yeah my bad I was just trying to give some context as to where the question was coming from.